# Opening newform/editform.aspx in SP Designer for further customization only shows default forms

Tags: sharepoint-designer, content-type, custom-form, form

On a document library I have a custom content type and I want to edit its forms in SP Designer. Going to the library in Designer and clicking on any of the forms in the Forms section shows a seemingly default form with only 3 columns:

[image]

What I expected to see was an editable version of my actual content type form editform.aspx (example):

[image]

I must be missing something really obvious here, but I couldn't find anyone with the same problem after doing some searches.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot customise a form for a document library with InfoPath in the same way as you can for a list form.

For one, each content type has its own form, and the default display, edit and new forms that you can see in SharePoint Designer at the Library's general property page are not the ones you want.

In SPD, go to the All Files pane on the left and navigate to the library. In the Forms folder, you will see a separate sub-folder for each content type, with the Word document (or whatever file) that is the template for the content type.

You can use InfoPath Designer to customize the Document Information Panel for a template and then publish that customised form. For more information see [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms563688%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies things. But I followed your instructions and could not find the same form on SP Designer that is accessible in SharePoint, it was still the default 3-column one. Strangely, in the content type sub-folders there are no form files listed either. Shouldn't the editform.aspx that is visible on SharePoint reside somewhere? Right now it feels like it's in limbo :)

Comment: The form that you see ***is*** the one used, but it pulls the columns in dynamically according to the content type. You cannot customize the columns in this form with SPD. You may be able to use JavaScript, depending on what you would like to achieve.